# How can I use @WithMockUser and pass my username and password from my properties file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am writing an integration test where the application has a basic auth applied with spring security. I am using @WithMockUser to tell mockMVC how to authenticate with my endpoints.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser(username="username", password="password")
```

This works but I am wondering if I can replace those strings with references to the values in my `application.properties` file similiar how you can do:

```
    @Value("${spring.security.user.name}")
    private String userName;
```

Is the above possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the `@WithMockUser` annotation and went with this solution which worked better for my use case. This method authenticates with the configured basic auth so going forward if it was to change it wouldn't be a problem.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class sampleTestIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only constant expressions to annotations but an alternative will be to create your own Security Context as explained here in the @WithSecurityContext chapter:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/test-method.html

I would also create my own test properties configuration file which will be used to read properties from the tests.